# jQuery checkbox enable disable

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a question about checkbox enabled and disabled.

If I check the checkbox, "personal training" should be disabled.

But i can't do it

**[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/nhhQz/8/)**.

```
$('#optionen :checkbox').on('change', function () {
    $('.menu li.' + this.className).toggleClass('hide');

});
```

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: But your checkbox has no `class` attribute...

Comment: What do you expect `this.className` to be?

Comment: Add this line:  alert(this.className);

Comment: if you want to hide/show ALL 'personal Training' ul li items you might try: `$('.menu li').toggleClass('versteckt');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#optionen :checkbox').on('change', function(){
```

This means "find `#optionen`, then find any checkboxes that are descendents of it". This finds this element:

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

You then bind an event handler to this element. Within the event handler, `this` points to the element.  The event handler looks for the element's `className` property. There is no `class` attribute set, so the `className` is an empty string. Your code therefore effectively looks like this:

```
$('.menu li.').toggleClass('hide');
```

This is obviously an invalid selector, so there is an error and nothing happens.

I'm not sure what your solution is; it might be as simple as adding a `class` property to your `input` element:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="leaf">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhhQz/13/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/nhhQz/10/

```
$('#optionen :checkbox').on('change', function(){
    $('.menu li').toggleClass('versteckt');
});
```

Is that what you want?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="optionen">
```

You do not have a class or id with the checkbox. I think you want the id of "optionen" with the checkbox. Then you also want to remove the reference to the class, unless you want to add a class inside the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two obvious solutions, the first give the `input` the class of `leaf`:

```
<span><input class="leaf" type="checkbox" />SERVICES</span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nhhQz/11/).

The second is  to correct the HTML (the *only* valid child elements for a `ul` (or `ol`) is an `li`):

```
<div id="optionen">
    <ul>
        <li><span><input type="checkbox" />SERVICES</span>

            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="first leaf"><a href="/site/personal_training">PERSONAL TRAINING</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="/site/personal_training">PERSONAL TRAINING</a>

                </li>
                <li class="leaf"><a href="/site/personal_training">PERSONAL TRAINING</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then use:

```
$('#optionen :checkbox').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('ul.menu li').toggleClass('versteckt');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nhhQz/14/).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: @aldimeola1122 if this answer solved your problem, please mark it by clicking the check on the left side